# Python will not run entire shell script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Starting with the following code , my objective was to create a restart command for my python bot.

```
result = {
    #cmds here
    prfx and 'restart':lambda _: call('./restart.sh', shell=True),
    }[cmd](_)

    room.message(result)
```

I have a lot of commands in this dictionary so I summarized the format. 
The command calls the shell script (restart.sh) , and is supposed to kill the bot process (bot.py) , and then reference to another shell script that then starts the bot process again.
[restart.sh]

```
pgrep -f bot.py #  pid
pkill -9 -f bot.py # kills the matching pid

sh ./start.sh #run start.sh
exit 0
```

[start.sh]

```
python bot.py
```

When running the restart command , the bot process is ended and does not continue the rest of the script.
[example : Bash]

```
Connecting to MySQL database...
connection established.
Connection closed.
ONLINE
[chatroom] Bot: ONLINE!: [ip]
[chatroom] user: >restart: [ip]
168747
169448
```

It will just show the two processes and terminate.

Comment: You're using this mechanism to have the bot restart itself? You can't do that. `pkill` will kill your parent. Use `execve()` to replace the old copy of the bot with the new one in memory directly. You don't need any `pkill` at all.

Comment: Also, why do you use `pgrep` if you're being *run from* the PID you want to replace? You can just look at your parent PID -- much less volatile and risky than string-matching on names.

Comment: (Also, don't use `kill -9` unless you really, **really** need to; it prevents processes from doing housekeeping, like flushing their write buffers on exit, so you can lose log messages or have datastores left in an unclean state).

Comment: execve() rewrites the process without you having to manually kill the process?

Comment: It literally replaces the current process-table entry with a different program.

Comment: that's how programs start other programs on UNIX -- it's how `subprocess.call()` works, for instance: First it calls `fork()` to make a copy of itself, then it calls an `execv`-family function to replace that copy with a different program. When you call `execv` without the fork, you're replacing the parent itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart yourself (that is to say, the current process), don't use `call()` (which I'm assuming is `subprocess.call()`) at all.

Instead, if this code is being run from `bot.py` itself (and that script is executable with a valid shebang):

```
os.execl(os.path.abspath(__file__), '_')
```

The `_` is a placeholder passed as `argv[0]`. You could put other command-line arguments after it, if you wished.

This replaces the running instance of `bot.py` with a new one inheriting the exact same PID.

Comment: Strangely doesn't seem to run, but os.path,abspathfile(__file__) prints out the location when tested

Comment: It has a shebang and the executable bit set? Do you get an error?

Comment: Using os.execl(sys.executable, 'python', __file__, *sys.argv[1:])  the program restarts, but there are two instances of my bot in the chatroom

Comment: How many threads or processes are associated with each instance of the bot?

Comment: (so, there are a few possibilities. One is that the CLOEXEC flag isn't set on your network connections, so the file descriptor stays open through the exec call; the other is that you have a different forked-off subprocess that's keeping the connection open).